# Migrate website content from Episerver to Tridion

Tags: web8, core-service

We have a requirement to migrate a website from Episerver CMS to Tridion. 
The episerver published content is on database and not on file system.
What can be the best approach using core services?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sure that Episerver has some form of [content retrieval API](https://www.google.com/search?q=episerver%20api), so you could pull content via that and then use the Core Service API to create the same (or similar) content in SDL Web, once you've created any necessary schemas.

A content migration is typically more complex than a simple retrieve and create though. You may want to only migrate some of the content and you may wish to change the content model to better suit the new CMS.

Plan carefully, as you may find that the changes you wish to make to the content's structure become more complex than you initially think and it may become more cost-effective to hire people to migrate content manually; This also gives people an opportunity to review and update existing content that is out of date.

Comment: Completely agree David. We need to provide the options and thought of checking other possible ways than recreating the content manually.

Answer (score 2):

adding on top of what David mentioned.

- First you need to define your content model on SDL Web
- Create schemas as per your content modeling.
- Component in SDL is also XML (but complex)
- You can read your content from existing CMS and convert to required XML format. but believe me its not Simple :) component link, images and adding component on page etc add some complexity in it.
- using core-service you can import those Component XML into SDL CM.